# How to set focus on ToolItem in ToolBar in Eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4, setfocus

How can I set focus on a MToolItem object in eclipse e4?

```
MToolBar mainToolBar = (MToolBar) modelService.find("maintoolbar", application);
MToolItem toolItem = (MToolItem) mainToolBar.getChildren().get(0);
```

I tried with getting its widget, then getting its control, but this does not work, getControl is only ment to «Return the control that is used to fill the bounds of the item when the item is a SEPARATOR.» So this cannot work.

```
MUIElement toolItemWidget = (MUIElement) toolItem.getWidget();
Control toolItemControl = (MUIElement) toolItemWidget.getControl(); // toolItemControl == null
```

Thank you for any hint …